# /lib/default-manifest.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So i get this error when i run my code in VS code after installing the "Mingw complier" how much of a pain in the ass does VS code have to be.

Chad Turbo C still runs likes a boss in my system even after installing fresh "Mingw" where as this thing just refuses.

I dont get what is wrong . And yeah i save and complied too.

[image]

Comment: Don't refer to images in your question. Include it here because hyperlinks maybe removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there if someone is looking out for this solution i just uninstalled VScode completely

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7NnYv6r_rY&ab_channel=CreativeNetworks

you can check this out

after that i installed mingw from scratch and tried it works.

And it was not easy idk why....